# Is it possible to filter items by Category in a custom item filter?

Tags: path-of-exile

The [item class page](https://pathofexile.fandom.com/wiki/Item_class) on the official wiki lists all classes with the `Item Class` name, the `Internal ID`, but also a `Category`.

Now using the `Category` in the item filter rules would be super convenient for me at the moment, but is it even possible? Or is it really necessary to manually list all classes in the said category to achieve the same goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, the most convenient way is to use [FilterBlade](https://www.filterblade.xyz/) in order to achieve all of your filtering needs. This is the most commonly used filter creator that we have.

In the customize section, there are sections for all of the tiers of flasks, armors and weapons and everything else. That is where you'll want to customize your loot filter accordingly.

You can also link your POE account directly to it, so you don't have to save and upload the file manually.

Comment: I'm guessing the fact a tool like this needs to exist means there really aren't easy ways of making filters... I'm personally not a fan of this _"shifting feature responsibilities on the community"_ approach (looking at you, Discord), but if it works, it works. Thanks!

Comment: @MartyCagas You'll learn to appreciate the work that the community does to make POE as good as it is. That's part of the charm but also part of the frustration of playing it. Filters, at the end of the day, is just a text file at its core. Some players make them manually, but there are just too many items and tiers to realistically do it yourself without some interface to help with it. You'll learn to embrace using community built tools, as it is really the best way to enhance your time with POE.

Comment: Oh I do appreciate the work the community does, I just believe that if something is near-needed to play a game or use a service, devs shouldn't pretend it's the community's job. But you're right - the sense of community is great with this game. The amount of people really living the game and sharing it with each other is amazing. c: